# How to change font of all footers in LibreOffice Write?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I have a multi-page text in LibreOffice Writer which has quite large fonts. I'm wondering how can I change the font of ALL footer texts at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to set header and footer font and size.

- For the existing document, under the menu item `View` | `Style`, [select *Header*, *Footer* and any other styles to modify](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Defining_Different_Headers_and_Footers).
- Change the font and attributes for those styles.

All headers and footers **using those styles** will change accordingly.

This presumes, of course, that whoever created the original document *used* styles to set the format. If the author *set each header and footer format separately*, then you'd need to find each header and footer and change it manually. sigh... It is *possible* to unzip an ODT document, manually edit styles and content, and resave the file, but it is not trivial and is prone to error -- *not* recommended.

[image: ODT Editing]

- For any *future* document, set them in the [LibreOffcie Writer Templates](https://www.howtogeek.com/340277/how-to-make-libreoffice-writer-templates/).

  - Select Writer's menu item `File` | `Templates>` | `Manage templates` (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>). Select a template to modify.
  - Under `View` | `Style`, [select *Header*, *Footer* and other styles to modify](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Defining_Different_Headers_and_Footers).
  - Change the font and attributes for those styles.
  - Save the template, and set it as the default or active template.